# Change Text of GroupingText (Asp Panel) Dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to change the GroupingText property, but i can't with jQuery .attr or .prop. This is my test code:

```js
jQuery("#testPanel").attr("GroupingText", "TextTest");
jQuery("#testPanel").prop("GroupingText", "TextTest");
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't kow asp.net, but GroupingText is not a DOM property or attribute. After doing some research, apparently ASP renders this into a fieldset and a legend, and whatever set in the 'GroupingText' property value is rendered as the  tag. Something like this (just an example)...

```
<asp:Panel ID="testPanel" runat="server" >                
<fieldlset>
<legend><asp:Label id="Label1" runat="server" /></legend>
</fieldset>
</asp:Panel>
```

So if you need to change this from jQuery, I think you should try to access the legend tag...

```
$('fieldset legend').text('TextTest');
```

Just trying to point you in some direction. Sorry for not being more specific, but my lack of ASP knowledge is a problem here!

I hope it helps

Comment: I set a legend object into the Panel as GroupingText with an Id so I can do a jQuery with it:
<asp:Panel ID="panelTest" GroupingText="<legend id='groupingTextTest' clientidmode='static'>Test Text</legend>" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">

It worked, thanks!! :)

Comment: Good to hear! Have a nice day and happy coding!! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Asp:Panel should render as a html div so you add attributes with **.attr**

`jQuery("#testPanel").attr("GroupingText", "TextTest");`

and may not with

`jQuery("#testPanel").prop("GroupingText", "TextTest");`

Please check once is it render as expected as a DIV in HTML?

Comment: GroupingText render as a legend object, so I set an object on the GroupingText property with an Id, so I can use jQuery with it. Thanks ;)